# With Sukuli, is it possible to apply an automorphism before matching the images?

Tags: sikuli

The best case scenario would be matching images projected in a 3D environment.

With Sikuli (or simply with OpenCV), the worst would be to match as is.

But a quicker algorithm would be to apply a planar transformation to the screen before searching for the images.

Is it possible with Sikuli, meaning, to we have access to this level of manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

> planar transformation

Could you explain what it means and what features of OpenCV would help to do that?

> access to this level of manipulation?

SikuliX 2.0.5+: the OpenCV Java API is available.

RaiMan from SikuliX